# c++11 implementation of Well Equidistributed Long-period Linear (WELL) without boost?

Tags: c++11, random

Sergiu Dotenco kindly contributed [his implementation based on boost](https://bitbucket.org/sergiu/random/src/tip/well.hpp?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default), could someone recommend an open-source c++11 style implementation, without boost? Google does provided some results, but this is a bit deep in math, I could not differentiate the quality of the implmentation.

Comment: Much of the boost used there have been absorbed into the standard library. The only tricky part is the use of `boost::mpl::apply` etc. That however seems to be only for optimising the compile time `%` calculation

Comment: It looks like you can replace the `mpl` with `constexpr` functions

Comment: @Caleth yeah the mpl is my headache. how to replace it with `constexpr`? could you give some example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how c++11 has made compile time programming (slightly) easier

```
template <typename UIntType> constexpr bool IsPowerOfTwo(UIntType r)
{
    return (r & (r - 1)) == 0;
}

namespace detail
{
    template<class UIntType, UIntType r, bool>
    struct ModuloHelper;

    template<class UIntType, UIntType r>
    struct ModuloHelper<UIntType, r, true>
    {
        template<class T>
        static T calc(T value)
        {
            return value & (r - 1);
        }
    };

    template<class UIntType, UIntType r>
    struct ModuloHelper<UIntType, r, false>
    {
        template<class T>
        static T calc(T value)
        {
            while (value >= r)
            { value -= r; }

            return value;
        }
    };
}

template<class UIntType, UIntType r>
struct Modulo : detail::ModuloHelper<UIntType, r, IsPowerOfTwo(r)>
```

Comment: As I look at this, you don't even need the definition `IsPowerOfTwo`, you can just put the expression `(r & (r - 1)) == 0` there. `IsPowerOfTwo` is reusable, however

Comment: Further, I'm not certain that a modern compiler wouldn't just *do all this* for you, when you write `x % r`, given that `r` is a template parameter

Comment: that's another topic, basically i'm looking for a way to nominally get rid of boost.

Comment: looking at the output of say https://godbolt.org/g/SFGioT it seems you can just drop it

Comment: sorry i don't get it here, from *where* you found that *what* could be dropped?

Comment: `Modulo<UintType, r>::calc(m)`, can be replaced with `m % r`, and you get the same (or better) binary. That is, compiler writers *also* know this trick, and they use it in generating code

Comment: is this `ModuloHelper` corresponding to the original `Power2Modulo`?  I'm a bit lost not sure how to replace the previous one with your code. Or would you mind give me an example at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47784402/how-to-rewrite-this-code-without-using-boost ?

Comment: You only use `ModuloHelper` in the implementation of `Modulo`, and it compile time selects between bitwise and (only applicable to modulo powers of two, "fast"), and repeated subtraction (always correct, "slow"). If you just use `m % r`, for compile time `r`, which all the uses of `Modulo` **must** be, a modern compiler does all that for you

Comment: i still couldn't get it. could you give me a compilable, updated version of https://bitbucket.org/sergiu/random/src/tip/well.hpp?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default that partially replaced its original Modulo implementation?

Comment: @Caleth The implementations are different. As you can see it wasn't _doing_ a modulo operation, there was a precondition on the range of `m`. You should be comparing the compiler output of those, if you want to prove that /a/ compiler optimizes it the same (I concur it might be faster. The linked implementation was intended for Boost, though, and is many years old. Things are/were different in those constraints)